# django non rel and google app engine: remote api issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am deploying a django-nonrel app on Google App Engine. The app deploys alright but I can't login to the remote shell.

This is my app.yaml file:

```
application: masnun
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine/deferred/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine/main/main.py
```

But I am getting an error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
Couldn't reach remote_api handler at https://masnun.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api(/.*)?.
Make sure you've deployed your project and installed a remote_api handler in app.yaml.>
```

Please help me out!

Update: When using Python2.5, getting this error:

```
DEBUG:google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc:Got http error, this is try #3
DEBUG:google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc:Sending HTTPS request:
GET /_ah/remote_api(/.*)? HTTPS/1.1
Host: masnun.appspot.com
X-appcfg-api-version: 1
Content-type: application/octet-stream
User-agent: Google-remote_api/1.0 Linux/2.6.35-25-generic Python/2.5.5.final.0
```

Comment: What command are you running? It looks like you're passing in a regular expression for the URL to fetch.

Comment: python manage.py deploy
python manage.py remote

Fails in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

> GET /_ah/remote_api(/.*)? HTTPS/1.1

If you notice, the URL contains invalid characters "(/.*)?" towards the end.

Assuming you are using django-nonrel, it is an easy fix. Open the file

```
djangoappengine/db/base.py
```

and change the line

```
self.remote_api_path = handler.url
```

to

```
self.remote_api_path = handler.url.split('(')[0] # remove '(/.*)' introduced in newer GAE
```

and that should take care of ensuring the URL is correct.

Comment: I am no longer working on the project. However, thanks for the reply and I accepted it :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this on app.yaml section handlers, first item:

```
handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
```

and deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the remote shell using

```
python manage.py remote shell
```

and only if you created your App Engine app with Google Accounts Authentication. But remote_api requires a deployed app and since your

```
python manage.py deploy
```

fails, the above error is normal.

What error do you get when you try to deploy?